# Enable Cors .web api core 1.1 with credentials

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

I'm using web api core 1.1 and angular 2.
I'm using credentials like a token and https with every HTTP request. When launching in Internet explorer everything is okay but when using chrome and firefox, I'm getting an error fetching my credential and Http requests. Can somebody tell me why I'm getting error? thanks

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddCors(opt =>
    {
       opt.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder =>
           builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials());
    });
    services.AddMvc();
    ...
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   ...
   app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
   app.UseMvc();
   ...
}
```

my ng2 code:

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class MyApiCallService implements OnInit{

constructor(private http: Http) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.fetchCredentials
       .subscribe(c => this.token = c
        ,error => { console.log(error) });
}
private fetchCredentials(): Observable<any> {

    var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:2762/api/someEndpoint';
    return this.http.get(apiUrl,{ withCredentials: true })
               .map(response => response.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will clean all custom headers.

You have to use `WithExposedHeaders("HeaderName")`

For example:

```
        app.UseCors(options =>
    {
        options.AllowAnyHeader();
        options.WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination");
        options.AllowAnyOrigin();
        options.AllowAnyMethod();
    });
```

So when you will make HTTP call from the client side, you would be able to see your header.